# Add Record to Existing Collection in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

I am attempting to develop a model in which a user can add the recipe they are viewing to an existing menu of recipes they have created, similar to adding a song to a custom playlist. I believe I have the models set up correctly (using a many to many through relationship) however I am unsure how to go about the adding of the actual records to a selected collection. Any guidance would be helpful. My code is as below.

Menus Controller

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_search

def show
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @menu = Menu.new
end

def edit
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @menu = current_user.menus.new(menu_params)

    if @menu.save
        redirect_to @menu
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])

    if @menu.update(menu_params)
        redirect_to @menu
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
    @menu.destroy

    redirect_to recipes_path
end

private
def menu_params
    params.require(:menu).permit(:title)
end
end
```

Menu Model

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :menu_recipes
has_many :recipes, through: :menu_recipes
end
```

menu_recipe Model

```
class MenuRecipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Recipe Model

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_one_attached :cover

has_many :menu_recipes
has_many :menus, through: :menu_recipes


end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
has_one_attached :profile_image
has_many :recipes
has_many :menus
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you build the new record off the user:

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
  # make sure you authenticate the user first
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]

  def new 
    @menu = current_user.menus.new
  end

  def create
    @menu = current_user.menus.new(menu_attributes)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then we can just add a select to the form where the user can select from his recipes:

```
# use form_with in Rails 5.1+
<%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
  ... other fields
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :recipe_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :recipe_ids, f.object.user.recipies, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`f.object` accesses the model instance wrapped by the form builder.

`recipe_ids` is a special setter/getter created by ActiveRecord for `has_many` associations. As you may have guesses it returns an array of ids and lets the association be set with an array of ids - automatically inserting/deleting rows in the join table in the process.

You then just need to whitelist the `recipe_ids` param:

```
def menu_attributes
  params.require(:menu)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, recipe_ids: [])
end
```

`recipe_ids: []` whitelists an array of permitted scalar types. Since this is a hash option it must be listed after any positional arguments to be syntactically valid.

```
rb(main):003:0> params.require(:menu).permit(:foo, recipe_ids: [], :bar)
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
```

Comment: I like how you are going about this but I am running into two issues: 1) I would like the user to be able to select multiple recipes in the form to add to each menu 2) What variable should i be calling in the view to display the recipe information? calling recipe.title is throwing a error saying "recipe" is not recognized.

Comment: 1.) add the `multiple: true` option to collection_select. 2). The association is has_many so you have to access `recipes` and iterate through the results. This is really a separate question though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like :

```
def add_recipe_to_menu
 menu = current_user.menus.find params[:id]
 recipe = current_user.recipes.find params[:recipe_id]

 menu.recipes << recipe
end
```

It will add a viewing recipe to existing menu of recipes.